# Escape curly braces in jQuery - Vegas plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

How can I escape curly braces to add additional images to the [Vegas Slideshow](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/)? The format for each slide is like this:

```
{ src:'image_url_string', fade:750 },
```

I'm trying to add slides to the slideshow dynamically like this:

```
$.each(homepage_images, function( index ) {
  { src:homepage_images[index]['url'], fade:750 },
});
```

When doing this, I get an 'undefined number' error. I believe its because I don't escape the curly braces? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need map method? Like this:

```
var data = $.map(homepage_images, function( element ) {
  return { src: element['url'], fade: 750 };
});
```

What is homepage_images? I mean types you are using is not quite clear in your question.